# Fancybox wrapper not auto-sizing correctly to image dimensions

Tags: jquery-plugins, fancybox, autosize

I'm having an issue with FancyBox. It's supposed to auto-resize the wrapper in accordance to the dimensions of the image. It's not doing that. Specifically it's too small.

Here's the FancyBox jQuery code I've used:

```
$("a[rel=photo_gallery]").fancybox({
    'type'              : 'image',
    'padding'           : 10,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'cyclic'            : true,
    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.7,
    'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'titleShow'         : false,
    'resize'            : 'Auto'
});
```

Has anyone else ever run into this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above did not work for me (FB 3beta).

This is my solution:

```css
.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-wrap *{
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -safari-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Figured it out ...

It was my CSS reset that was being tripped-up by the FancyBox CSS. I reset the box-sizing style of DIV's to 'border-box'.

The fix was to go into the FancyBox CSS and declare the wrap, outer, and inner DIV's box-sizing to be 'content-box'.

Like so:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px;
z-index: 1101;
display: none;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-safari-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}

#fancybox-outer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #FFF;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-safari-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}

#fancybox-inner {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-safari-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Hopefully that will help somebody else that runs into this.

Comment: it did help! I fear this may be why I rejected some other popup managers. took me too long to realize that there was a css conflict

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with arbitrary HTML showing in the popup. I found this was all that was necessary to fix it (when using Eric Meyer's reset.css) is this:

```
.fancybox-overlay
{
    line-height: normal;    
}
```

The offending code in the reset.css file was this

```
body 
{
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Disclaimer: Tested only in IE9 and Chrome - but it appears to work.
This is for whatever the latest version of fancybox is at time of writing.

Comment: Please comment if anybody finds this not to be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

I also found that getting rid of the global reset for box-sizing helped :

```
/*
*,
input[type="search"] {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
box-sizing:         border-box;
*/
```

The annoying part is finding all the items that were relying on border-box and then enabling it for JUST those items.  Luckily for me there were only 3... that I've found so far.  Firebug / Developer Tools helped a lot to figure it out though.