# How to make resizable Fancybox v2 image and border change size together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to create resizable Fancybox v2 window by using jQuery UI.

The only thing that happens - is to change the image size or border size separately.

HTML:

```
<a rel="gallery" title="Image" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Resizable image:
http://jsfiddle.net/g2pjR/

JS:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    autoResize: false,
    afterShow: function () {$('.fancybox-image').resizable();}    
});
```

Resizable border:
http://jsfiddle.net/HrVKa/

JS:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    autoResize: false,
    afterShow: function () {$('.fancybox-skin').resizable();}    
});
```

How to force the image to change its size together with the border?

Comment: Those two clips of code here look very similar, is that the intent?  (OK, they look to be the same code really) but that is not what the fiddle has

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss
Sorry, I misprinted. Now it's changed to the correct version.

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963734/fancybox-wrapper-not-auto-sizing-correctly-to-image-dimensions

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss

Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI Resizable Widget includes the `alsoResize` option so you could bind *resizable* to the `.fancybox-wrap` selector and `alsoResize` to `.fancybox-inner` and `.fancybox-image` selectors like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    autoResize: false,
    afterShow: function () {
        $('.fancybox-wrap').resizable({
            alsoResize: ".fancybox-inner, .fancybox-image"
        });
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ww3SP/)**

Comment: Thanks, it certainly that I looked for.
It's a pity that I didn't notice this option. ;-)